# Hvie: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift

I have some an issue with hive meta

Using "`netstat -apn|grep 9083`", the port 9083 is free, and no process regarding hive is running.

Then run "`bin/hive --service metastore`" or "`bin/hive --service metastore -p 9083 &`" (I tried other port numbers, but have the same issue), following errors are logged:

```
       ERROR [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:startMetaStore(5256)) - 
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
       ...
       ERROR [main]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:main(5138)) - Metastore Thrift Server threw an exception...
    org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
```

Below are some of my configurations of hive:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://192.168.38.128:9083</value>
  <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
</property>


<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
  <description>Port number of HiveServer2 Thrift interface.
  Can be overridden by setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT</description>
</property>
```

Any help please?

Comment: Is your metastore database running? Mysql or Postgres?

Comment: Yes. "service mysqld status" shows mysql is running.   @cricket_007

Comment: Alright, that's good.. I'm not sure where `0.0.0.0` is getting set, though